# Should a SaaS Documentation portal be personalized?

Tags: usability, web-app, documentation, document-design

Should a documentation portal for a large SaaS company with multiple applications, that has all the docs for all the apps in one docs portal, switch to a curated/personalized view after a user logs in? - that only shows documentation on their subscribed app(s)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed. This is known as the Principle of Intentionality. You can learn about it in a psychology oriented article [**A Principle of Intentionality**](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2017.00137/full), and the UX-focused article [**Intentionality in User Experience**](https://dorve.com/blog/intentionality-in-user-experience-empathize-users/) *(disclaimer: I wrote it)*.

Simply put: **your user will want to perform a single action, or a limited set of actions**.

Let's say your documentation's whole range contains 100 items, but you have the option to identify your users and serve a very specific subset of items based on their preferences. This will only increase performance and decrease the possibility of errors, and you can test it using scientific methods like [**Hick-Hyman's Law**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law) (also known as **Hick's Law**).

## In short

If it's within your possibilities, then yes, you should use a curated/personalized option, just like you say